Create std::formatter for template class for std::print support
I have a struct defined inside of a template class and I would like to create a std::formatter for that struct to be able to print that struct instances by using std::print.
The class I have:
template <typename ValueType, std::size_t SizeOfEachStack> requires (SizeOfEachStack > 0)
class ThreeStack
{
public:
    struct StackProperties
    {
        std::size_t min_index{0};
        std::size_t max_index{0};
        std::size_t current_index{0};
    };

    ThreeStack()
    {
        for(std::size_t stack_number = 0; stack_number < num_of_stacks; stack_number++)
        {
            stack_properties.at(stack_number).min_index = stack_number * SizeOfEachStack;
            stack_properties.at(stack_number).current_index = stack_properties.at(stack_number).min_index;
            stack_properties.at(stack_number).max_index = stack_properties.at(stack_number).min_index + SizeOfEachStack - 1;
        }
    };

    // Print function to print the internal arrays.
    void print_internal_arrays()
    {
        for(std::size_t stack_number = 0; stack_number < num_of_stacks; stack_number++)
        {
            std::print("Stack {}: {}\n", stack_number, stack_properties.at(stack_number));
        }
    }

private:
    static constexpr size_t num_of_stacks{3};
    std::array<ThreeStack::StackProperties, num_of_stacks> stack_properties{};
};

And here is the std::formatter I created and which does not work:
// Create a std::formatter for the ThreeStack::StackProperties struct for any ThreeStack<ValueType, SizeOfEachStack>.
template <typename ValueType, std::size_t SizeOfEachStack>
struct std::formatter<ThreeStack<ValueType, SizeOfEachStack>::StackProperties>
{
    constexpr auto parse(format_parse_context& ctx) { return ctx.begin(); }

    template <typename FormatContext>
    auto format(const ThreeStack<ValueType, SizeOfEachStack>::StackProperties& stack_properties, FormatContext& ctx)
    {
        return format_to(ctx.out(), "min_index: {}, max_index: {}, current_index: {}", stack_properties.min_index, stack_properties.max_index, stack_properties.current_index);
    }
};

I got the below compile error for this std::formatter:
<source>:43:78: error: type/value mismatch at argument 1 in template parameter list for 'template<class _Tp, class _CharT> struct std::formatter'
   43 | struct std::formatter<ThreeStack<ValueType, SizeOfEachStack>::StackProperties>
      |                                                                              ^
<source>:43:78: note:   expected a type, got 'ThreeStack<ValueType, SizeOfEachStack>::StackProperties'
<source>:43:13: error: template class without a name
   43 | struct std::formatter<ThreeStack<ValueType, SizeOfEachStack>::StackProperties>
      |             ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
Compiler returned: 1

https://godbolt.org/z/qeKsMrb4Y
How can you I get the behavior I want with std::formatter?

That's not how partial specialization works, we are in the non-deduced context.

@康桓瑋, on the other hand, if we solve this part, why this compiles just fine with MSVC latest and doesn't compile with GCC?

@DamirTenishev Because your formatter definition has no constraints, it is a better candidate for formatters for primitive types like integers than libstdc++, which uses constrained templates for those types.

Compiler is asking you to tag the template nested type with typename keyword: template<typename X, auto Y> struct std::formatter<typename Z<X,Y>::W>. Otherwise it assumes the template nested identifier to be an object or a function.

I’m not sure I understand what you are trying to do. Maybe I missed something. StackProperties does not depend on the template parameters; therefore, you can define it outside of ThreeStack, and all your problems will be solved.
struct StackProperties
{
  std::size_t min_index{ 0 };
  std::size_t max_index{ 0 };
  std::size_t current_index{ 0 };
};

template <>
struct std::formatter<StackProperties>
{
  template<class ParseContext>
  constexpr ParseContext::iterator parse(ParseContext& ctx) 
  { 
    return ctx.begin(); 
  }

  template<class FmtContext>
  FmtContext::iterator format(const StackProperties& s, FmtContext& ctx) const
  {
    return std::format_to(ctx.out(), "min_index: {}, max_index: {}, current_index: {}", s.min_index, s.max_index, s.current_index);
  }
};

template <typename ValueType, std::size_t SizeOfEachStack> requires (SizeOfEachStack > 0)
class ThreeStack
//...

[EDIT]
If you want to maintain the structure in your code, you could define a concept to identify the inner structure. While I’m not an expert in metaprogramming, one approach could be to add a unique signature (e.g., a static constexpr member) to the inner structure and define a concept to check for its presence and value. Alternatively, you could define a concept that checks for the existence of the inner structure (run it).
#include <iostream>
#include <format>


template < typename T >
class a_t
{
public:

  struct b_t
  {
    using type_t = T;
    static constexpr std::string_view signature_ = "my_sign";
    T m_{};
  };

  void f()
  {
    std::cout << std::format("{}", b_);
  }

  b_t b_;
};


template <typename B>
concept has_my_sign = requires 
{
  { B::signature_ } -> std::convertible_to<std::string_view>;
} 
&& 
B::signature_ == "my_sign";


template <typename B>
concept is_expected_type = requires
{
  typename B::type_t;
}
&&
std::same_as<B, typename a_t<typename B::type_t>::b_t>;


template < typename T > requires is_expected_type < T >
struct std::formatter< T >
{
  template<class ParseContext>
  constexpr ParseContext::iterator parse(ParseContext& ctx)
  {
    return ctx.begin();
  }

  template<class FmtContext>
  FmtContext::iterator format(const T& b, FmtContext& ctx) const
  {
    return std::format_to(ctx.out(), "a_.b_.m_: {}\n", b.m_);
  }
};

int main()
{
  a_t<int> a1;
  a1.f();

  a_t<double> a2;
  a2.f();
}


Yes, it works but is there a way to achieve the same thing without moving the struct to out of ThreeStack class?

@sakcakoca If your goal is to emphasize the dependency between these two structures, the cleanest approach would be to enclose both in a meaningful namespace.

I'm just wondering how to write std::formatter for a struct with this code structure. You can change the example and imagine that StackProperties is also dependent on one of these template parameters. In this case, how should std::formatter be written?

@sakcakoca See the edited answer.
